# ARM Thumb extra POP and BX in epilogue

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I disassembled some object files for an embedded target to inspect the code size, and noticed a peculiarly "asymmetric" prologue-epilogue pair. It began with a push for 4 registers including `lr`, and ended with a pop of 3 registers, followed by a pop of 1 register, and then a `bx` to the popped register.

```
push {r4, r5, r7, lr}
...
pop  {r4, r5, r7}
pop  {r0}
bx   r0
```

I eventually realized that this is because there is no encodable register past `r7` for this instruction, so there is no `pop {r4, r5, r7, r8}` and no `pop {r4, r5, r7, r0}`, because the register list must be in order, due to the encoding. I wonder why it didn't allocate `r6` at all for this function, but I'm guessing it's for some ABI reason I missed.

Is there an ABI reason that a simple `pop {r4, r5, r7, pc}` was not used?

Comment: Some CPUs (e.g. ARM7TDMI) support calling a Thumb function from "classic" ARM code but they do not support changing back from Thumb to "classic" ARM using `pop {pc}`. (Newer CPUs support this.) For this reason, `bx r[x]` (e.g. `bx r0`) must be used to return from a function if it is not guaranteed that the Thumb function has not been called from "classic" ARM code if the code has been compiled for such a CPU.

Comment: Yeah, I had an inkling that would be the case. That makes sense. Not to imply that saving 4 bytes here and there would matter to me very much, even for my embedded target, but I'm nonetheless curious whether there is a way to "assert" that the caller is always in Thumb mode.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: You could post that as an answer, unless there's an existing duplicate.  BTW, GCC has a `-mno-thumb-interwork` option that hopefully lets it assume there's no mode switching, just always-thumb or always-arm according to `-mthumb` or `-marm`.

Comment: what assembler are you using and what architecture did you select.  and what architecture are you running this on.

Comment: What martin pointed out is clearly stated in the arm documentation.

Comment: @old_timer: Clearly stated, if you know exactly which documentation to check!  Unlike many questions about how a specific instruction works or why a compiler is using it, this doesn't seem like a bad or obvious question to me.  It's not like ARM documentation is easy to google; that often finds the half-assed compiler(?) documentation entries that don't mention details like this.  Or Keil pages are sometimes good, but aren't official ARM docs.

Comment: It is clear to those who have lived through all the arm architectures :)  This is particular to **thumb1** or the original thumb.  An extension, like **thumb2** (both of which are nebulous concepts) don't need it.  I suspect that changing `-march` or `-mcpu` will create better code.  Thumb1 was not as expressive as ARM and there was a question of whether a particular code set would be optimal on either.  I think only ARMv4 and lower might generate this code.  I had the same issue on AS400, changing to Power4 from the default 1990 CPU improved performance by ~25%.  Pick the best minimum!

Comment: armv5 architectural reference manual (arm arm), the armv7-a architectural reference manual.  armv6-m, armv7-m armv8-m.   basically if it is about instructions then the architectural reference manuals, from arm.  nobody else.  not the programmers reference, those cause more problems than they solve. not the assembly language manuals those cause more problems than they solve.    secondary is the technical reference manuals but those do not apply here.

Comment: it is an armv4t vs armv5t thing yes, thumb or arm mode, even though in this case it is a thumb instruction (upper registers like lr not available).

Comment: I believe from armv4 through to armv7 each generation/version added more instructions that could do interworking, I dont think the whole jump was between v4 and v5 but evolved to what it is in v7.  but that is documented.   sadly there is no armv6 full sized level doc, you have to look between the two manuals.  are you using an arm11?

Comment: My target is indeed one of those old ARM7TDMI's, so I'm stuck with Thumb 1 there (or ARM, but most of its memories use a 16-bit bus). I got curious of what the compiler would do for ARMv7 in Thumb 2 only mode, and it indeed went with the `pop {..., pc}` way, so that explains that, I suppose.

Comment: @MonatheMonad  You can answer your own question.  I think you have all the details?  I think the `-mno-thumb-interwork`, using a `static` function or optimize with whole program might all get rid of it.. but you have the tools to see.  I tired to investigate with godbolt, but you did not give a complete example.